# Setting font-size for date-picker

Tags: nativescript

How can I set the font size for date-picker?

Stackoverflow is complaining about the content of this question - so let me ramble on. Can the style, class or font attributes be set for the date-picker.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - No, you can not set text-related CSSproperties for date picker module.
Better explanation is given [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1903#issuecomment-230411199)